# DataTable error "No Data Available in Table", table shrinks

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatable

I'm trying to apply mdbootstrap's table plugin to a table. The body of the table is pulling the data from a google sheet document. 
[image: When the page loads, the table loads but the first row says "No Data Available in Table"]

When I hit the sort icon on the columns, all the data disappears but the row `No Data Available in Table` still remains.

I want to correct it so `No Data Available in Table` disappears and I'm able to sort the data coming in via google sheets.

```
[<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>TEST</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/addons/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/addons/datatables.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1l-YCSglU72QEk35AWM0B-OCbLG7eVch4yvuxX2eFLrw/2/public/values?alt=json", function (data) {

var sheetData = data.feed.entry;

var i;
for (i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {

var col1 = data.feed.entry\[i\]\['gsx$col1'\]\['$t'\];
var col2 = data.feed.entry\[i\]\['gsx$col2'\]\['$t'\];
var col3 = data.feed.entry\[i\]\['gsx$col3'\]\['$t'\];
var col4 = data.feed.entry\[i\]\['gsx$col4'\]\['$t'\];

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += ('<tr>'+'<td>'+col1+'</td>'+'<td>'+col2+'</td>'+'<td>'+col3+'</td>'+'<td>'+col4+'</td>'+'</tr>');

}
});
  </script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
  });
  </script>

  <!-- Start your project here-->
  <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="th-sm">COL1
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">COL2
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">COL3
        </th>
        <th class="th-sm">COL4
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="demo"></tbody>

  </table>
  <!-- Start your project here-->
</body>

</html>]
```

Comment: instead of innerHTML +=  use innerHTML = , you are appending with +=

Comment: When I do that, the "No Data Available in Table" row disappears, but it only shows the last row in the data table. Also when I hit the sort button, the data disappears and is replaced with "No Data Available in Table".

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this way, 
every time make the body clear. before appending new rows, so that whenever you do sorting or next or search it will clear current rows and show new

```
var i;
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = ""; // this will delete the innerhtml
for (i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {

var col1 = data.feed.entry\[i\]\['gsx$col1'\]\['$t'\];
var col2 = data.feed.entry\[i\]\['gsx$col2'\]\['$t'\];
var col3 = data.feed.entry\[i\]\['gsx$col3'\]\['$t'\];
var col4 = data.feed.entry\[i\]\['gsx$col4'\]\['$t'\];

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += ('<tr>'+'<td>'+col1+'</td>'+'<td>'+col2+'</td>'+'<td>'+col3+'</td>'+'<td>'+col4+'</td>'+'</tr>');

}
```

Comment: Ahhh! Cool! Thx, I'll try it out :D

Comment: I hope it solves your problem if yes you can accept it and vote up.